# How do I get docx.js children method to work?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a web app to generate `.docx` files.

So I found `docx.js`. I got a basic file to generate. With the use of constants, it's not much of a problem.

However, when using the children method, it only generates an empty .docx.

```
doc.addSection({
    children: [
        new Paragraph({
            children: [new TextRun("Hello World")],
        }),
    ],
});
```

https://codepen.io/DVGeoffrey/pen/ExxgEJv here is the pen.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get this to work properly?
Thank you :-)

Comment: I guess it's a version problem. Use 4.0.0 Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3xhezb5w/2)

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. But this doesn't show a working child method.